# Couldn't find executable named deployer-gnulinux

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after i type rosrun ocl deployer-gnulinux -ldebug -s deploy.ops
i get above error. I have installed the orocos-toolchain properly and also sourced it. affter i type ros ocl and than press the tab key nothng comes. Can't i run deployment node from ros command now? i can clearly see that deployment-gnulinux is build in the the build directories. does Ros supports this anymore? Or i have to use deployment-gnulinux only?
i was looking [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ocl) page.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285688/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-deployer-gnulinux/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, after i copy the deployer-gnulinux exeutable from bin folder to ocl folder it is working, as show by the error itslef, but i do'nt know this is good or now for latter. the full error was:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named deployer-gnulinux below /home/robot/Desktop/ws/underlay_isolated/install_isolated/share/ocl
```

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0